# Rotation and translation animations for RecyclerView not running at the same time

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

I am working on adding some animations for the widgets in my RecyclerView.  I want an image to start on the left side of the screen and translate it to the right while it is spinning.  If I try to do the translation animation on its own it works fine.  If I try to do the rotation animation on its own it works fine.  If I try to run them both at the same time it doesn’t look right at all.  The image follows a curved path when translating.  I think that it might be trying to rotate around the position that the translation will end at, but it is hard to tell.  I used an AnimationSet to try to get it working since putting both animations in a single XML didn’t work, but it didn’t help.

```
translation_to_right.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="-100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:duration="3000"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"/>
    />
</set>
```

```
rotate.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="360"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="3000"
    />
</set>
```

```
  @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Animation translateRight = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(parentContext, R.anim.translation_to_right);
        Animation rotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(parentContext, R.anim.rotate);
        AnimationSet animationSet = new AnimationSet(false);
        animationSet.addAnimation(translateRight);
        animationSet.addAnimation(rotate);
        holder.imageView.startAnimation(animationSet);
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the `View` into a surrounding `ViewGroup`, e.g. a `FrameLayout`, so that it fits inside even when rotating. Then apply the rotation to the `View` and the translation to the `FrameLayout`.